# Title of webpage printing as None, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from [this website](https://www.stfrancismedicalcenter.com/find-a-provider/adegbenga-a-adetola-md/) and am not able to get the title of the webpage.

My code-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.stfrancismedicalcenter.com/find-a-provider/"

content = requests.get(url = base_url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

profile_link = soup.find("a", {"class": "flex-top-between-block-500"}).get("href")
profile_url = base_url + profile_link[1:]

profile_content = requests.get(url = profile_url).content
profile_soup = BeautifulSoup(profile_content, "html.parser")
print(profile_soup.title.string)
```

This is the output am getting.

```
[Running] python -u "d:\Personal\CS\Web Scrapping\first.py"
None

[Done] exited with code=0 in 3.592 seconds
```

I'd like some suggestions on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue here is that the concatinated path to profile is not correct, the part `find-a-provider` is duplicated and so it becomes:

```
https://www.stfrancismedicalcenter.com/find-a-provider//find-a-provider/adegbenga-a-adetola-md/
```

Instead using your url define a specific ""baseUrl:

```
profile_url = 'https://www.stfrancismedicalcenter.com' + profile_link
```

or

```
baseUrl = 'https://www.stfrancismedicalcenter.com'
profile_url =  baseUrl + profile_link
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.stfrancismedicalcenter.com/find-a-provider"
baseUrl = 'https://www.stfrancismedicalcenter.com'

content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

profile_link = soup.find("a", {"class": "flex-top-between-block-500"}).get("href")
profile_url = baseUrl + profile_link

profile_content = requests.get(url = profile_url).content
profile_soup = BeautifulSoup(profile_content, "html.parser")
profile_soup.title.text
```

##### Output

```
Adegbenga A. Adetola MD
```

Comment: I changed the code so now the link is "https://www.stfrancismedicalcenter.com/find-a-provider/find-a-provider/adegbenga-a-adetola-md/
". I still face the same issue.

Comment: The code you shared works though, thanks!